# Reset second jquery drop down select box when first is changed

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am using the following script to fetch records from my database and put them into select boxes using jquery, ajax and php. The select boxes are also styled and added features using Select 2
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select-2.1.html#basics

If I select a customer from the first select box and then select a vehicle from the second box this works fine........if I then change my mind and select a different company, the vehicle box stays on the last reg and doesn't revert back to :

```
  <option>Select A Customers Vehicle</option>
```

If I then click on the vehicle select box I can select the vehicles from the company and the 'ghost vehicle' from the last query vanishes, so it does work, its just when I change the company again I would like it just to reset the vehicle box back to its default again until I select a vehicle.

This is the Main Page :

```
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <link href="js/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="js/select2/select2.js"></script>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() { $("select").select2(); });

        </script>
    <?php
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
    if (isset($_SESSION['key'])) {$sessionkey = $_SESSION['key'];}else {$sessionkey = '';}
    if ($sessionkey == 'sbhjbKA2bsbhjbKA209bhjbKA2bsbhjbKA209KaXff19u0bsbhjbKA209KaXff19u9Ka'){
    include 'connectmysqli.php';
         echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template/template.css" />';
    echo '<strong class="pagetitle">Add New Sale</strong>
     ';
    $saleID = rand().rand();
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    echo '<form method="post" action="addsalesubmit.php">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$saleID.'" name="saleID" id="saleID">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$today.'" name="date" id="date">';
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Select test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#customer').on('change', function (){
            $.getJSON('select.php', {customerId: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                var options = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['reg'] + ' - ' + data[x]['make'] + ' - ' + data[x]['model'] + '</option>';
                }
                $('#vehicle').html(options);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <br>
            <select id="customer">
            <option>Please Select / Search For A Customer</option>
            <?php
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `customers`
    SQL;
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($row['bussinessname'] == ''){$name = $row['title'].' '.$name = $row['firstname'].' '.$name = $row['surname'];}else
    {$name = $row['bussinessname'];}
    echo '<option value="'.$row['customerID'].'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select></p>';
            ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
        <select id="vehicle">
      <option>Select A Customers Vehicle</option>
    </select>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {echo '<h1 style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:red;">Access Denied !</h1>';}
    ?>
```

This is the php script that does all the fetching :

```
    <?php include 'connectmysqli.php'; ?>
    <?php
    $id = $_GET['customerId'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE customerID = ' . (int)$id;
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    $json = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $json[] = array(
        'id' => $row['vehicleID'],
        'reg' => $row['reg'],
        'make' => $row['make'],
        'model' => $row['model']
      );
    }
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every call of the `onchange` first empty the second dropdown

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#customer').on('change', function (){
$('#vehicle').html("<option value=''>Select</option>");// add this on each call then add the options when data receives from the request
        $.getJSON('select.php', {customerId: $(this).val()}, function(data){
            var options = '';
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['reg'] + ' - ' + data[x]['make'] + ' - ' + data[x]['model'] + '</option>';
            }
            $('#vehicle').html(options);
          $("select").select2();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, iv tried this but it still stays in the last reg selected

Comment: shouldn't it be an append() instead of html()

Comment: @steven no it shouldn't append because append will add the option in existing one and using `html` will first removes the previous options then adds the new one

Comment: @lian Simpson can you provide the live url or any fiddle ??

Comment: Its running locally at the moment, I can put it into jsfiddle but I wouldnt load anything because of the database lookups. All of the code is above, its only a simple page :)

Comment: Ok, iv found that if I remove the Jquery Select 2 from    $(document).ready(function() { $("select").select2(); });
it works just fine, but I need that to add the search function to the select, so it looks like its overriding the jquery trying to reset it t default.

Comment: Try my edited answer in callback i have again called the `$("select").select2();`

Answer (score 1):

the following is not asked but i have to advice you that there are some additional errors in your code:

```
echo '</select></p>';
        ?>
        </select>
```

there are two `</select>` and one `</p>` without a starting `<p>` at the end of your customer select box

Comment: Thanks, I have removed those now